# Javascript Closure and WebRTC callback issues

Tags: javascript, callback, closures, webrtc

I'm running into this problem where I'm creating a closure and stepping through with the debugger, the variable connectingClientId is set correctly within the closure callback (localOfferCreated). When the callback is called by createOffer the connectedClientId is undefined. How could this be the circumstance? Been banging my head against the wall all night on this one.

```
function publishStream(handShakeInitiator, connectingClientId) {
    var localOfferCreated = offerClosure(connectingClientId);
    var localIceCandidate = iceClosure(connectingClientId);
    peerConnections[connectingClientId] = new RTCPeerConnection(peerConnectionConfig);
    peerConnections[connectingClientId].onicecandidate = localIceCandidate;

    peerConnections[connectingClientId].addStream(localStream);

    if (handShakeInitiator) {
        peerConnections[connectingClientId].createOffer(localOfferCreated, createOfferError, offerOptions);
    }
}

function offerClosure(id) {

    var connectingClientId = id;

    function offerCreated(description) {
        peerConnections[connectingClientId].setLocalDescription(description, function (connectingClientId) {
            webSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
                'control': signalConstants.sendToClient,
                'cid': connectingClientId,
                'sdp': description
            }));
        }, function () {
            console.log('Error setting description.');
        });
    };

    return offerCreated;
}
```

Note these from the debugger:

connectingClientId is set -
[image: connectingClientSet]

connectingClientId is unset upon call -
[image: connectingClientUnset]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [RTCPeerConnection.setLocalDescription](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/setLocalDescription)

> **successCallback**
>   Is a Function without parameter which will be called
>   when the description has been successfully set. At this point, one can
>   send the offer to a remote server that can forward it to a remote
>   client

You are redefining `connectingClientID` by having it as an inner function parameter. Remember that a named function argument is an implicit variable declaration, and as what docs said, it'll be undefined as the success callback don't give any parameters. JavaScript functions have access to their outer scope, so your anonymous function does not need this arg to be passed, it can simply refer to it creating a closure.

```
function offerCreated(description) {
    peerConnections[connectingClientId].setLocalDescription(description, function() {  
        webSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
            control: signalConstants.sendToClient,
            cid: connectingClientId,
            sdp: description
        }));
    }, function () {
        console.log('Error setting description.');
    });
};
```

Comment: Added my died in half way answer to yours, hope you don't mind it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Man man man, the small things overlooked sometimes.